# Can't see the add-in option of F# in the Visual Studio 2010 integrated Shell

Tags: visual-studio-2010, f#

I installed the F# InstallFSharp.msi, and then the visual studio 2010 shell.

Then, if I understood correctly there should be an add-in available in tools->add-in manager.

There wasn't. So I "Repaired" the InstallFSharp.msi to see if the order of install as important.

Nothing.

Then I uninstalled InstallFSharp.msi and reinstalled it.

Nothing.

Question: how do I install VS studio shell with F#?

Regards,
P. Fonseca

Comment: Note also you should first install the shell, then install the F# msi, in that order.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that was true of a previous version of the tools, but now F# integration doesn't show up as an addin.  Instead, you should find F# Interactive under View/Other Windows, and when you go to File/New/File.../Script or File/New Project... you should see F# options.

Comment: @user655673 - If this answer worked for you, you should mark it as the answer by clicking the hollow check-mark.